# How can I call req.flash() from inside the mongoose save function?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, flash-message

Upon finding duplicate user entries in my database, I want to flash a message to the view using req.flash(). However, the only parameters allowed in the User.save() function are errors and the results of the save. How can I get the request object in there too so that if there is 
an error (i.e. duplicate entry), the user is notified?

requires

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Quote = require('../models/quotes')
const User = require('../models/users')
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')
const flash = require('express-flash-messages')

const passport = require('passport')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const saltRounds = 10
```

get request:

```
/* route handling for SIGNUP page. */
router.get('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    const flashMessages = res.locals.getMessages()
    console.log('flash:', flashMessages)
    if (flashMessages.error) {
        console.log('flash:', flashMessages)
        res.render('signup', {
            showErrors: true,
            signupErrors: flashMessages.error
        })
    } else {
        console.log('no flash errors detected.')
        res.render('signup')
    }
})
```

post request:

```
    /* route handling for submission to SIGNUP page */
// this is all just front end validation, with no relation to the database. I think flash messages use that
router.post('/signup/users', (req, res, next) => {
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username field cannot be empty.').notEmpty()
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username must be between 4-30 characters long.').len(4, 30)
    req.checkBody('email', 'The email you entered is invalid, please try again.').isEmail()
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email address must be between 4-100 characters long, please try again.').len(4, 100)
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100)
    // req.checkBody('password', 'Password must include one lowercase character, one uppercase character, a number, and a special character.').matches(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,}$/, 'i')
    req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Password must be between 8-100 characters long.').len(8, 100)
    req.checkBody('passwordMatch', 'Passwords do not match, please try again.').equals(req.body.password)

    // Additional validation to ensure username is alphanumeric with underscores and dashes
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username can only contain letters, numbers, or underscores.').matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/, 'i')

    const errors = req.validationErrors()

    if(errors || flashMessages.error) {
        res.render('signup', {
            errors: errors,
            showErrors: true,
            signupErrors: flashMessages.error
        })
    } else {
        let password = req.body.password
        bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
            user = new User()
            user.username = req.body.username
            user.email = req.body.email
            user.password = hash


// PROBLEM STARTS HERE

            user.save((err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    // add flash message here to let user know something was wrong!
                    const flashMessages = res.locals.getMessages()
                    console.log('flash', flashMessages)
                    console.log("Your error: ", err.message)
                    if (err.message.indexOf("duplicate key error") > -1) {
                        req.flash('signupErrors', "Username already in use.")
                        console.log(req.flash("hi"))
                        res.redirect('/signup')
                        console.log("Made it down here.")
                    } else {
                        req.flash('signupErrors', "There was a problem with your registration.")
                        console.log("Made it wayyyyyy down here.")
                        res.redirect('/signup')
                    }

// AND ENDS HERE

                } else {
                    User.find({}).sort({ _id:-1 }).limit(1)
                    .exec((err, newuser) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        } else {

                            // logins user through passport function
                            req.login(newuser[0], (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log("Login error 1: " + err)
                                    console.log("Login error 2: " + newuser[0])
                                    console.log("Login error 3: " + newuser[0]._id)
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Login sucess BULK: " + newuser[0])
                                    console.log("Login success ._id: " + newuser[0]._id)
                                    res.redirect('/home')
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(next)
                }
            })
        })
    }
})

/* route handling for submission to LOGIN page */
router.post('/login/users', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))
```

Comment: The variable `req` should still be accessible within that function. It may not be passed as an argument but variables from the surrounding function are still in scope. What makes you think that it isn't available?

Comment: You seem to be storing messages using the key `signupErrors`, e.g. `res.flash('signupErrors', ...` yet when you read the messages in your `/signup` route you're looking for messages under the key `error`. There's also this line that looks suspect: `if(errors || flashMessages.error) {`, where is `flashMessages` defined?

Comment: Yes I agree. I know for sure there is a cleaner way to do this, I just could not figure out how for the life of me. flashMessages is defined at the top of the get request as res.locals. The reason I think req is unavailable is becuase when I call req.flash(), nothing happens in the view. As you seem to be alluding to though, it is most likely something to do with the way I have structured my code.

Comment: My comments were not related to the structure of your code, I was pointing out apparent mistakes that need to be fixed. If a variable isn't available then an error will be thrown, it won't just silently not work. The `if` check I quoted was from your `post` route, where is that variable `flashMessages` defined? The similarly named variable at the top of your `get` handler is not the same variable.

Comment: I finally fixed my error skirtle, and it involved flashMessages being undefined and the variable names I was passing back and forth to the view. Thank you sincerely for your help!